# How to compare two text files and output any missing or extra strings from each files?

Tags: perl, compare

I have these two sample files to compare their contents. I need to compare these two files and output any missing or extra string from any of the file.

Ref.txt:

```
bjkdsl
dookn
cmshdksldj
```

New.txt:

```
cmshdksldj
unklskdjs
dookn
```

output:

```
unklskdjs :missing string in Ref.txt    
bjkdsl :missing string in New.txt
```

Update: Sample text file 1

Ref.txt:

```
bjkdsl
dookn
cmshdksldj
```

New.txt:

```
cmshdksldj
unklskdjs
dookn
bjkdsl
```

Output :

```
unklskdjs : missing string in new.txt
```

sample files 2:

Ref.txt:

```
cmshdksldj
unklskdjs
dookn
bjkdsl
```

New.txt:

```
cmshdksldj
unklskdjs
dookn
bjkdsl
```

Output:

```
Ref.txt is same as New.txt
```

Thanks for all the helps but I still trying to get the codes for every condition that may occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'text1.txt' or die $!;
chomp(my @arr1 = <$fh>);

open my $fh2, '<', 'text2.txt' or die $!;
chomp(my @arr2 = <$fh2>);

my (%m1, %m2);
# populate %m1 hash with keys from @arr1 array using hash slice
@m1{@arr1} = ();
# ..
@m2{@arr2} = ();

# remove from %m1 hash keys which are found in @arr2,
# leaving thus only these which are unique to @arr1 array
delete @m1{@arr2};
# ..
delete @m2{@arr1};

# print only keys found in %m2 which by now are only these not found in @arr1
# this could be just print..for keys %m2; but order of element would be lost
print "$_ is missing from text 1\n" for grep { exists $m2{$_} } @arr2;
# ..
print "$_ is missing from text 2\n" for grep { exists $m1{$_} } @arr1;
```

output

```
unklskdjs is missing from text 1
bjkdsl is missing from text 2
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you comment this to explain what it's doing; it's not going to be obvious to a perl novice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i getting this `is missing from text 1` when i compare same content from two text files. How should I get rid of this ?

Comment: @annel you probably have empty line in one of them. Check them with diff, ie. `diff text1.txt text2.txt`

Comment: Thanks. I did have empty line in text 1.txt. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete the key from the hash when it's found in the second file. At the end traverse the hash and print all keys that you didn't delete:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %exclude;

open my $fh, '<', 'text2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        $exclude{$_}++;
}

open $fh, '<', 'text1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        if ( exists $exclude{ $_ } ) {
                delete $exclude{ $_ };
        }
        else {
                print "$_ is missing from text2\n";
        }
}

for ( keys %exclude ) {
        print "$_ is missing from text1\n";
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
bjkdsl is missing from text2
unklskdjs is missing from text1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Very much appreciate it. It did yields the output. But what if text 1 is bjkdsl dookn cmshdksldj and text 2 is cmshdksldj bjkdsl unklskdjs dookn, it still prints out the line of missing from text1 which shouldn't be display.

Comment: @annel: Why not? It exists in `file2` but not in `file1`.

Comment: But i getting this output:

`unklskdjs is missing from ref
     is missing from ref`